# how to send data from java class to servlet

Tags: java, servlets

I am new to programming. What I am trying here is to accept values from database in dao class and send them to servlet. So how do I accept values from java class in my servlet?

This is my dao class:

```
...
{         
    //connection establishment
    //Database access and retrival of data

    //objects of data access class are created
    UserDO userdo = new UserDO();
    RegDO regDO = new RegDO();
    AddressDO addressDO = new AddressDO();
    while(rs.next())
    {
        //values are set in data object
        userdo.setName(rs.getString("name"));
        addressDO.setStreetname(rs.getString("street_name"));
        addressDO.setCity(rs.getString("city"));
        regDO.setGender(rs.getString("gender"));
        regDO.setReg_date(rs.getString("reg_date"));
    }
}


catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.setStackTrace(null);
        }


finally
        {
            if(rs!=null)
            {
                rs.close();
            }
            if(conn!=null)
            {
                conn.close();
            }
        } 
        disDo.wait(); 
        return disDo;

//connection closing
```

my servlet class id given below:

```
// objects of do class is being created
UserDO user    = new UserDO();
AddressDO add  = new AddressDO();
RegDO reg      = new RegDO();
DisplayDO disDo= new DisplayDO();
System.out.println("In display method");
int userid =Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("userid"));
disDo.setUserid(userid);
System.out.println("userid= "+userid);
try
{               
    disDo=dao.Display(disDo);
} 
catch (Exception e) 
{               
    e.printStackTrace();
}
// have to accept values from dao class here

String name,street_name,city,gender,reg_date;

// the values are set and accepted by a jsp file
request.setAttribute("name", name);
request.setAttribute("street_name", street_name);
request.setAttribute("city",city);
request.setAttribute("gender", gender);
request.setAttribute("reg_date", reg_date);
RequestDispatcher rd= request.getRequestDispatcher("display_1.jsp");
try
{               
    rd.forward(request, response);
}
catch (ServletException e) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

once again problem is how to pass parameters from java to servlet?

Comment: Create an instance of DAO , and call the exact method in the DAO , to get the values.

Comment: rookieB thanks for your response.. i hav already tried ur suggestion.. but unfortunately, that's not working..

Comment: And what is not working? Any errors?

Comment: rookieB's suggestion is valid. What happened when you tried it? A Servlet is just like any other class - you can still instantiate and call methods on other classes.

Comment: I also think that trying to program Servlets when you are new to programming is not a good idea. It's like trying to read Shakespeare when you've only just got the hang of learning to read at all.

Comment: RookieB,NickJ    actually i am getting null values in servlet whereas in dao class i am getting the values in dao class..

Comment: could u give me a code please .. i have a feeling we are not talking about the same thing..

Answer (score 0):

Few points I would like to add :

1. "accept values from database in dao class and send them to servlet" - should be achieved by writing a method that retrieves values from database and return those values. (Might be LIST, or even an object). remember one DAO class can have many methods.
2. "how do i accept values from java class in my servlet" - Same as how you do it for other classes. Make an instance of the DAO as i mentioned in my comment and call the exact method.

You are saying

```
return disDO
```

But I can't see you setting anything on your `disDO` object. So it will definitely be `NULL`. You are setting the value in other objects , and not your `disDO`. Look your `while loop`

Comment: But from DAO you need to return them to servlet? Do you understand return statement?

Comment: Accepting values from db is working perfectly.. -i printed the values and they were correct- wheras i did create an instance of dao class but its returning null values.. i dont know why.. :|

Comment: yes i have returned disdo(which is the object of the method in question) sorry about the naming..

Comment: And where is your disdo object in your DAO class?

Comment: i didnt put the entire code here.. sorry abt tat.. chk catch(Exception e)
  {
   e.setStackTrace(null);
  }
  finally
  {
   if(rs!=null)
   {
    rs.close();
   }
   if(conn!=null)
   {
    conn.close();
   }
  } 
  disDo.wait(); 
  return disDo;

Comment: OK , but you are not setting anything on disdo. look at the while loop